# Roughness Zero material not reflecting objects

Tags: roughness

[image] How can I make the table top reflecting the objects too and not only the world scene

Answer (score 2):

Set metallic of the table to 1, and enable screen space reflections:

[image]

So in render view you will get:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Turn up the *Transmission* on the material to 1, or some other value depending on how reflective you want it.